# adding platform specific flags in makefile

Tags: linux, windows, makefile, mingw, autotools

I need to set a couple of flags in my makefile that needs are only windows specific i.e., I dont want them to be "seen" on other OS. I am using MinGW to build my project. These are the flags I want to set only for windows:

```
AM_LDFLAGS += -lws2_32
AM_LDFLAGS += -Xlinker --allow-multiple-definition
```

This is what I did in my makefile.am:

```
SYS := $(shell gcc -dumpmachine)
ifneq (, $(findstring mingw, $(SYS)))
    AM_LDFLAGS += -lws2_32
    AM_LDFLAGS += -Xlinker --allow-multiple-definition
endif
```

When I did `autoreconf -isf`, it failed with following messages:

```
Makefile.am:34: endif without if
Makefile.am:30: `:='-style assignments are not portable
Makefile.am:30: shell gcc -dumpmachine: non-POSIX variable name
Makefile.am:30: (probably a GNU make extension)
Makefile.am:31: findstring mingw, $(SYS: non-POSIX variable name
Makefile.am:31: (probably a GNU make extension)
aminclude.mk:162: .PHONY was already defined in condition TRUE, which includes condition DX_COND_doc ...
Makefile.am:80:   `aminclude.mk' included from here
core/Makefile.mk:169: ... `.PHONY' previously defined here
Makefile.am:56:   `core/Makefile.mk' included from here
Makefile.am:271: <D: non-POSIX variable name
Makefile.am:230: user variable `distdir' defined here...
/mingw/share/automake-1.11/am/distdir.am: ... overrides Automake variable `distdir' defined here
autoreconf-2.68: automake failed with exit status: 1
```

Any suggestions on how to handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add the check to your configure.ac, something like this:

```
AC_CANONICAL_HOST
case $host_os in
  *mingw*) mingw=true ;;
  *) mingw=false ;;
esac
AM_CONDITIONAL([MINGW], [test x$mingw = xtrue])
```

Then in Makefile.am, you can do

```
if MINGW
AM_LDFLAGS += -lws2_32
AM_LDFLAGS += -Xlinker --allow-multiple-definition
endif
```

Make sure you don't indent the body of the if condition in Makefile.am!

Comment: Better to use predefined `$host_os` which will handle cross-compilation scenario

Comment: @vitalyster I tried this in configure.ac: 

`AC_CANONICAL_HOST
case $host_os in
  windows* )
        AM_LDFLAGS += -lws2_32
        AM_LDFLAGS += -Xlinker --allow-multiple-definition
        ;;
    *)
        AM_LDFLAGS += 
        AM_LDFLAGS += 
        ;;
esac` but did not work. I will try what @ptomato suggested and see if it works.

Comment: @ptomato I tried what you suggested, make clean; make failed with an strtok related error.
so I edited the makefile.am as `if !MINGW.....`.This doesn't make sense. Am I missing something here?

Comment: @ptomato This is the exact error I got: `collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status make[1]: *** [tape/tape.la] Error 1 make[1]: Leaving directory`...So, I thought to test it out in Linux machine, so by doing above, the Linux machine SHOULD NOT see those flags but it was seeing those flags and errored out. Is there any mistake in above solution?

Comment: @SrinGupta: that's not the error you got; that's just Make complaining about the error. The real error will be above that in the output. You can see what the result of the check is by doing something like `AC_MSG_CHECKING([for mingw]) AC_MSG_RESULT([$mingw])`

Comment: @ptomato changed `true` to `yes` and `false` to `no` and `AM_CONDITIONAL(MINGW, test $mmingw = yes)`, its working. Although I don't know why setting `true` and `false` did not work.

Comment: I had a typo; there should not have been a dash before `-x$mingw`.

Comment: @ptomato I will try without dash but is there something wrong in using `yes no` instead of `true false`?